# FormBuilder input fields not showing in a row in - flutter (Form builder package)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield, flutter-dependencies, formbuilder

In need to display multipe text fields in a Row using [flutter_form_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder) package,
here is my code (Not working)

```
FormBuilder(
           
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
    
              FormBuilderTextField(
                attribute: 'product_name',
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Product Name',
                ),
                onChanged: _onChanged,       
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  FormBuilderTextField(
                  attribute: 'product_before',
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Product Name',
                  ),
                onChanged: _onChanged,),
                FormBuilderTextField(
                attribute: 'product_after',
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Product Name',
                ),
                onChanged: _onChanged,
                ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              
             
            ]))
```

package link : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder
[image: like this]

Comment: Can you provide the `_onChanged` function's code?

Comment: It just print the value "   final ValueChanged _onChanged = (val) => print(val);  "

Comment: Then, you need to put `setState` function

Comment: you can use container with width MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /3,